# is Rust's "match" as fast as C's "switch" for bytes?

Tags: c, switch-statement, rust, match

If I have Rust code like:

```
let x: u8;
let y = match x {
    0 => "0",
    1 => "1",
    // ...
    255 => "255",
    _ => unreachable!(),
};
```

will it be as fast (or faster) than the C code:

```
byte x;
char* y;
switch(x) {
  case 0: y = "0"; break;
  case 1: y = "1"; break;
  ...
  case 255: y = "255"; break;
}
```

I am wondering if Rust implements anything like a jump table in the assembly.

Comment: "Is this equivalent to the following C code" No. `byte` is non-standard type and `*char` will emit compile error.

Comment: I will fix the question, I mean are they as fast as eachother.

Comment: Both of your code snippets are still broken. Please fix those, too. And you're likely to get an unsatisfying answer. I'm pretty sure both compile down to pretty much the same assembly. Rust uses LLVM for optimization, the same backend as `clang` uses.

Comment: Additionally, it's going to matter **which compiler** (and compiler version) you are using. I guarantee that there's a C compiler out there that doesn't produce a jump table for that code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LLVM does what it thinks is fastest with match. Sometimes that's a jump table, sometimes it's not. It depends on the exact match, including how many features of match you're using. (Like @, if, and anything else.)

Comment: Glad to hear it :)